# Correct usage of professionals' versus professionals

Tags: grammaticality

Which is the correct sentence?

> "...through our extensive professionals’ network..."

or

> "...through our extensive network of professionals"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Through our extensive professionals’ network

This refers to the network belonging to the professionals, if such a thing is possible. I'm not sure this is what you want to convey.

---

---

> Through our extensive network of professionals

This refers to *our* network, the network belongs to the author, and is a network whose constituents are professionals.

Answer (score -1):

Both usages show possession and are equally correct.